# Does $f(x)\mid f'(x)$, where $f'(x)$ is the derivative of $f(x)$, and $f(x), f'(x)\in \mathbb{F[x]}$?

Tags: ring-theory

Herstein says *"Let $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ have a nontrivial common factor. Then $f(x)\mid f'(x)$."*

$f'(x)$ is the derivative of $f(x)$, and $f(x), f'(x)\in \mathbb{F[x]}$.

How is this possible?

Let the common factor be $q(x)$. Then $f(x)=q(x)h(x)$, and $f'(x)=q(x)h'(x)+q'(x)h(x)=q(x)i(x)$, where $q(x), h(x), i(x)\in \mathbb{F[x]}$.

If $f(x)\mid f'(x)$, then the quotient will be $\dfrac{i(x)}{h(x)}$, and it is not obvious that this element should be there in the ring $F[x]$, as that would imply the multiplicative inverse of $i(x)$ is present in the ring.

Comment: For reference, this is stated on pg. 192 of the Second Edition. For other editions, it is part of corollary 1 of Lemma 5.6 of the chapter on Fields.

Comment: Do you know that $f(x)$ is the irreducible polynomial of some element?

Comment: But I don't think that is the assumption in this case, although it is of the lemma which the author goes on to prove. If $f(x)$ is irreducible, then the only nontrivial factor it can have in common with $f'(x)$ is $f(x)$ itself. Considering $f(x)$ is a polynomial $\in \mathbb{F[x]}$, I don't think that's a possibility we can consider, as $deg(f'(x))=deg(f(x))-1$

Comment: In Corollary $1$ to Lemma $5.6$ of the $1964$ edition it is hypothesized the $\,f(x)\in F[x]\,$ is irreducible, so the inference is clear.

Comment: I changed f(x)|f'(x) to f(x)\mid f'(x).  The latter automatically supplies proper spacing, thus: $\displaystyle f(x)|f'(x)$ versus $\displaystyle f(x)\mid f'(x)$.  The latter is also standard usage.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you're right, based on what you've written. Consider for example $f(x)=x^3-x^2\in\Bbb R[x]$. Then $f(x)=x(x^2-x)$ and $f'(x)=3x^2-2x=x(3x-2)$, but we certainly can't say that $f$ divides $f'$ in $\Bbb R[x]$.

Now, if there are some further conditions on $f$ that you didn't mention, then this might work out.

Answer (score 0):

This statement isn't true in general. Take for example $f(x)=(x-1)^2$ so that $f'(x)=2(x-1)$. In this case, clearly $f(x)\nmid f'(x)$.

On the other hand, if we know $f(x)$ is the irreducible polynomial of some element, say $\alpha$, then $f(x)$ divides *every* polynomial that has $\alpha$ as a root. In particular, if $\alpha$ is a repeated root, then $f(x)\mid f'(x)$.

Comment: If you are talking about the minimal polynomial $f$ of an element (I confess I don't know what the irreducible polynomial of an element is) over a field, then the last condition implies $f'=0$ by degree consideration, whence $f$ is constant... So this situation does not happen. Did you have another more general situation in mind? Of course, it could be noted that if $f$ is constant, then $f$ divides $f'$.

Comment: @Clayton- That made things abundantly clear. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Correction to my comment: it happens iff $\alpha$ is not algebraic over $F$, i.e. its minimal polynomial is $0$.

Comment: @julien: In characteristic $0$, you're correct, but in can happen in characteristic $p$ as $x^p+1=(x+1)^p$, so the derivative will be identically $0$.

Comment: Right, add characteristic zero to my comments...It seems that I only know characteristic zero fields... Still, over any field, the conclusion is that $f'=0$. And in characteristic $2$, your first paragraph does not work. Just to give me an excuse for assuming the characteristic was zero...

Comment: Also, I know that the minimal polynomial of an element over a field is irreducible, but are there really places/books where it is called the irreducible polynomial? Just curious because I had never seen that before.

Comment: @julien: I just finished my graduate algebra courses using Serge Lang's text, and this is the terminology he employs (although, in class we admittedly flipped back and forth between minimal and irreducible polynomial).

Comment: Ok, thank you Clayton.